# facebook manage pages details

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I am trying to get access of facebook pages through php SDK

Using php-sdk-4.0.13

Facebook app version v2.2

And redirecting url like this 
https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=http//www.example.com/john114614/settings&state=5255ad86fea19ab0e8d61776890d0224&scope=manage_pages&client_id=558252720931906&ret=login&sdk=php-sdk-4.0.13&ext=1431067051&hash=AeYVfkUZEGLy0wD_

Its stay at 302 status and redirecting to  http//www.example.com/john114614/settings?code=blahbla.......

App id is perfect and more over this problem faced from last 5-6 days before that its working fine.

Please help me how i can resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: when ever i am calling this api request didn't get any response from api call. am checked the status of api call show 302 .........

please check link for screenshot..

https://plus.google.com/103708502894971567288/posts/HyiraCEgU34?pid=6146393150727490306&oid=103708502894971567288

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for above problem

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession;

use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

use Facebook\GraphUser;

use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('appid84', '0secret0a626c6');

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://tmd.local/fblogin.php');

try {

  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();


}
 catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
}

 catch(\Exception $ex) {
}
if ($session) {

  var_dump($session);

}

else
{
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();

 header("location:".$loginUrl);

  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a `response_type`, see

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3#login

In your case, you get a `code` which your'd need to exchange to an Access Token afterwards. If you specify your login url as follows

https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/john114614/settings&scope=manage_pages&client_id=558252720931906&response_type=token

it should work IMHO.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Well, there will always be a redirect. You have to examine the query string parameters of the redirected URL. The Access Token is passed as parameter. It's all in the docs.